# Euclidean space in non-countable dimensions?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, hilbert-spaces

We can define a Euclidean space of finite dimension $\mathbb{E}^n$ is as an **affine space modeled over the normed vector space** $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|)$, which allows to construct a distance, being the $\mathbb{E}^n$ a complete metric space.

I wonder if:

1. is it possible to say that some Hilbert spaces of dimension $\aleph_0$ are also Euclidean space of infinite dimension?
2. Is it possible to define Euclidean spaces of dimension $\aleph_1, \aleph_2, \dots$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Given a set $X$, you can define $\ell^2(X)=L^2(X,\mathcal P(X),\mu)$, where $(X,\mathcal P(X),\mu)$ is the counting measure on the parts of $X$. These are Hilbert spaces with respect to the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int fg\,d\mu$. $\ell^2(X)$ is linearly isometric (actually, homeomorphic) to $\ell^2(Y)$ if and only if $\lvert X\rvert=\lvert Y\rvert$. Moreover, for all Hilbert spaces $E$ there is some cardinal $\kappa$ such that $E$ is linearly isometric to $\ell^2(\kappa)$: this $\kappa$ is the cardinality of any Hilbert basis. Not to be confused with the algebraic dimension, though.

Comment: For instance, there are no Hilbert spaces of algebraic dimension $\ge\aleph_0$ and $<2^{\aleph_0}$, but $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ is definitely a thing (in fact, it's usually indicated by just $\ell^2$).